# JProfiler identifying "Unclosed Collected" connections when using JDBCTemplate from spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate, jprofiler

We are testing vendor code, and to help with performance we installed JProfiler 9.1.1.  JProfiler has been helpful identifying performance issues.

One thing that JProfiler identified was "Unclosed Collected" connections.

JProfiler defines "Unclosed Collected" connections as:

> a virtual connection where the connection object that has been handed out by the
>   database pool has been garbage collected, but close() has not been called on it. This is a definite connection leak.

Per JProfiler, the method that is triggering "Unclosed Collected" connection is:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(
      java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[ ],
      org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper)
```

We are using SQL Server 2012, and JBoss EAP 6.3.3.

Data source configuration

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/abcclmicdds" pool-name="clmDataSource" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:IP_GOES_HERE</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>sqlserver2012</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>60</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>USERNAME_GOES_HERE</user-name>
        <password>PASSWORD_GOES_HERE</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
    <timeout>
        <idle-timeout-minutes>0</idle-timeout-minutes>
    </timeout>
    <statement>
        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
    </statement>
</datasource>
```

The vendor came back and claims that JProfiler is misidentifying this as "Unclosed Collected".

JdbcTemplate is designed to automatically close connections for you. Has anyone came across something like this before?  Could JProfiler be misidentifying these connections?

Comment: What JDBC connection pool do you use?

Comment: Thanks.  I left that out.  We are connecting to Microsoft SQL Server 2012.  And we are using JBoss EAP 6.3.3 to handle the connection pool.

Comment: Can you send me a snapshot to support@ej-technologies.com? If it's larger than 10MB, please ask me for FTP credentials at that email address.